# How to make a very large forward slash in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

this is the result I'd like to achieve:

[image]

I tried various commands to make the forward slash larger, for instance I tried the `\left. (...) \right /` or composing multiple `\mathlarger` commands but I couldn't get the desired result, with both of them the forward slash is bigger than normal but not even close to be large enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}


\title{Big forwardslash}
\author{Niccolò Della Rocca}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

\[\left. 
                 V\otimes_{\mathbb C}W= \mathbb C\left[V\times W\right]\middle\slash
                \text{Span}
                    \begin{Bmatrix}
                        (\underline{v}+\underline{v}',\underline{w}) - (\underline{v},\underline{w}) - (\underline{v}',\underline{w}) \\
                        (\underline{v},\underline{w}+\underline{w}') - (\underline{v},\underline{w}) - (\underline{v},\underline{w}')\\
                        a(\underline{v},\underline{w}) - (a\underline{v},\underline{w})\\ 
                        a(\underline{v},\underline{w}) - (\underline{v},a\underline{w})\\
                        a\in\mathbb C,\:\underline{v}\in V,\:\underline{w}\in W
                    \end{Bmatrix}
                 \right.
            \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\middle\slash` or `\middle\fracslash` in `unicode-math`, between `\left.` and `\right.` to get an extensible slash. This doesn’t work with every font out there, but it does with most of them.

Comment: @Davislor: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I tried that already and it's still too small. If needed I can attach a picture of what I get with that.

Comment: A MWE would help, I think. Thanks!

Comment: So please do share the code you’ve tried before.

Comment: @Davislor: Added an MWE

Comment: Thank you! That’s very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it, but *should* you? Do you really think this is a good formula to display? I really think it isn't, for several reasons:

1. it's very big and difficult to read;
2. it's *not* the way tensor products are defined (it is *one* way, but one never uses it, relying instead on the universal property).

Anyway, here's a way to do it.

First of all:

1. `\mathbb C` is not proper syntax; use `\mathbb{C}`;
2. better yet, *define* your own command;
3. underlining symbols for vectors is very old-fashioned markup;
4. better defining an abstract command that can be modified without chasing the document for `\underline`;
5. `\text{Span}` is wrong syntax: try it in the statement of a theorem;
6. use `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Now the promised code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\vct}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\reallybigslash}{O{2em}mm}
 {% #1 = width (default 2em)
  % #2 = left part
  % #3 = right part
  #2\!
  \begin{gathered}
  \bafforasta_reallybigslash:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \end{gathered}
  \!#3
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bafforasta_reallybigslash:nnn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { $\displaystyle#2$ }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { $\displaystyle#3$ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box + \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box }
                { \box_ht:N \l_tmpb_box + \box_dp:N \l_tmpb_box }
   }
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_linewidth:n { 0.75pt }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0pt , 0pt }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { #1 , \l_tmpa_dim }
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
  \draw_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\title{Big forwardslash}
\author{Niccolò Della Rocca}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

\[
\reallybigslash{
  V\otimes_{\CC}W= \CC[V\times W]
}{
  \Span\left\{
  \begin{matrix}
    (\vct{v}+\vct{v}',\vct{w}) - (\vct{v},\vct{w}) - (\vct{v}',\vct{w}) \\
    (\vct{v},\vct{w}+\vct{w}') - (\vct{v},\vct{w}) - (\vct{v},\vct{w}')\\
    a(\vct{v},\vct{w}) - (a\vct{v},\vct{w})\\ 
    a(\vct{v},\vct{w}) - (\vct{v},a\vct{w})\\
    a\in\CC,\vct{v}\in V,\vct{w}\in W
  \end{matrix}
  \right\}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\reallybigslash` command has an optional argument to set the slash's width. For instance, with

```
\reallybigslash[1em]{...}{...}
```

(where the dots stand for the same as before) you get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did the trick as expected. About the point 2 of your first list, in our classes we saw both this definition and that based on the universal properties so I thought it was a good idea to include it in my notes, even though I agree the latter is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

The `unicode-math` package supports auto-scaling `\middle\slash` and `\middle\fracslash` (if the math font does).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\title{Big forwardslash}
\author{Niccolò Della Rocca}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

\[\left. 
                \left. V\otimes_{\mathbb C}W= \mathbb C[V\times W\right]\middle\slash
                \text{Span}
                    \begin{Bmatrix}
                        (\underline{v}+\underline{v}',\underline{w}) - (\underline{v},\underline{w}) - (\underline{v}',\underline{w}) \\
                        (\underline{v},\underline{w}+\underline{w}') - (\underline{v},\underline{w}) - (\underline{v},\underline{w}')\\
                        a(\underline{v},\underline{w}) - (a\underline{v},\underline{w})\\ 
                        a(\underline{v},\underline{w}) - (\underline{v},a\underline{w})\\
                        a\in\mathbb C,\:\underline{v}\in V,\:\underline{w}\in W
                    \end{Bmatrix}
                 \right.
            \]

\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

This requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: Yeah that does it, but unfortunately importing unicode-math causes other things I'd like to keep to get messed up. For instance the distance between subscript and superscript changed making some lines unnecessarily high and also \mathscr font changed. Any workaround?

Comment: @Bafforasta You could try loading a different font. By default, `unicode-math` sets `\mathscr` to the same font as `\mathcal`, but you can change that by, e.g., `\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}` followed by `\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr},  StylisticSet=1, Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math}`.